# How to determine significance of a binomial test on a sample

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm looking to determine the significance of the result of a binomial test of a sample of a population. Example: Given a group of 10,000 people, I ask 1,000 if they prefer iOS or android. 550 respond that they prefer android.

For that test of the sample, the p-value (determined using python's scipy module) is about 0.0017. So I read that as only 0.17% probability there is no actual difference in preference.

What I want to know now, is how significant those results are against the population of 10,000. I.e. what is the probability that among the 10,000 there is actually no preference.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the concrete names of the operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are testing is:

$H_0$ : the probability of answering I prefer smart phone 1 is $p = 0.5$

The conclusion of your test is that you reject the null hypothesis (well it depends of the type 1 error rate you had a priori defined). Notice that nowhere the total size of the group is mentionned. Your conclusion is valid regardless of the the size of the group.